# Selenium Tests Passing in Docker Locally But Failing AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Flask project for which I'm running tests with Selenium. I have the tests running locally in Docker, but the same tests fail when I deploy the Docker image to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

It's a simple project that uses a Flask endpoint to trigger a task that fetches products from a website and uploads a .txt file to Google Drive.
This is the app.py file:

```py
import os
import re
from flask import Flask, Response
import time
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from threading import Thread
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account


app = Flask(__name__)

def get_name(file_path):
    patron1 = r"\\([^\\]+)\.txt$"
    patron2 = r"/([^/]+)\.txt$"

    # Buscar la coincidencia en la cadena
    resultado = re.search(patron1, file_path)

    # Si se encuentra una coincidencia
    if resultado:
        texto_extraido = resultado.group(1)
        print("Texto extraído:", texto_extraido)

    else:
        resultado = re.search(patron2, file_path)
        if resultado:
            texto_extraido = resultado.group(1)
            print("Texto extraído:", texto_extraido)
            
        else:
            print("No se encontró coincidencia.")
            texto_extraido = file_path
    
    return texto_extraido


def crear_fichero(data):
    # Obtener la fecha y hora actual
    now = datetime.now()

    # Formatear la fecha y hora
    timestamp = now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")

    # Ruta de la carpeta y archivo
    carpeta_destino = 'libros'

    # Comprobar si la carpeta existe y crearla si no
    if not os.path.exists(carpeta_destino):
        os.makedirs(carpeta_destino)
        print(f"Se ha creado la carpeta '{carpeta_destino}'.")

    # Escribir la variable en el archivo
    archivo_path = os.path.join(carpeta_destino, f'{timestamp}_books.txt')

    try:
        with open(archivo_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as archivo:
            archivo.write(data)
        print(f"Se ha escrito en el archivo '{archivo_path}'.")
        return archivo_path

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error al escribir en el archivo '{archivo_path}': {e}")
        return ""


def subir_fichero(ruta_fichero):
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = creds.json'
    PARENT_FOLDER_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

    # INICIAR SESION
    def authenticate():
        creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
        return creds

    # SUBIR UN ARCHIVO A DRIVE
    def upload_file(file_path):
        creds = authenticate()
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
        
        file_metadata = {
            'name' : get_name(ruta_fichero),
            'parents' : [PARENT_FOLDER_ID]
        }
        
        file = service.files().create(
            body=file_metadata,
            media_body=file_path
        ).execute()
        

    print(ruta_fichero)
    upload_file(ruta_fichero)


def listar_libros_async():
    def listar_libros():
        print("Empezando Selenium scrape.....\n")

        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') #desactivar el sandbox en el contenedor
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') #no entorno gráfico
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-smh-usage') # no usar memoria smh
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
        # Configurar el tamaño de la ventana (opcional)45
        #chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
        # Deshabilitar la aceleración de hardware (opcional)
        chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        #chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
        chrome_options.add_argument("enable-automation")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)        
        #driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

        url = 'https://www.neuralnine.com/books/'

        driver.get(url)

        # Esperar 5 segundos antes de realizar la siguiente acción
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_to_be(url))

        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features='lxml')

        headings = soup.find_all(name= 'h2' , attrs={'class': 'elementor-heading-title'})

        res = ""
        for heading in headings:
            res += f"{heading.getText()}\n"

        time.sleep(1)

        driver.quit()

        print("\nTarea completada con éxito!!!!")
        file_path = crear_fichero(res)
        subir_fichero(file_path)

    # Ejecutar listar_libros() en un hilo separado
    thread = Thread(target=listar_libros)
    thread.start()



@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "WELCOME!!!"



@app.route('/go')
def bye():
    listar_libros_async()
    return "PRUEBA SELENIUM"



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

My Dockerrun.aws.json file to deploy the Docker image looks like this:

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Image": {
      "Name": "ejooroo/docker-img",
      "Update": "true"
    },
    "Ports": [
      {
        "ContainerPort": "80"
      }
    ]
}
```

And the corresponding Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get install -y wget unzip && \
    wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    rm google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb && \
    apt-get clean

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

To test I've been building the image, and running it with this docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2.3'

services:
  libros:
    image: docker-img
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    shm_size: 2g
```

All of my tests pass locally, but none pass in Elastic Beanstalk. I'm getting this error in the log file:

```
172.17.0.1 - - [10/Feb/2024 18:31:51] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Exception in thread Thread-45 (listar_libros):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/app/app.py", line 143, in listar_libros
    driver.get(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 357, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {"url": url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 348, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

Why would tests pass in my local Docker environment, but not in Elastic Beanstalk?
I need some help.
Thanks.